# audio and TTS DUCK issue

Tags: ios, objective-c, text-to-speech

I have tried many different methods to duck playing music while my application is running and try to use TTS command to play some custom TTS speech but no luck.

My current code to duck audio while playing TTS is as below:

```
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setDelegate: self];
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory: AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback error: nil];
UInt32 allowMixing = 1;
AudioSessionSetProperty (
                         kAudioSessionProperty_OverrideCategoryMixWithOthers,
                         sizeof (allowMixing),
                         &allowMixing
                         );

allowMixing = YES;
AudioSessionSetProperty(kAudioSessionProperty_OtherMixableAudioShouldDuck, sizeof(allowMixing), &allowMixing);   
AudioSessionSetActive(YES);
```

But still there is issue with volume

with this my volume goes down but after my TTS ends I use below code to level up the ducked music.

```
AudioSessionSetActive(NO);
```

But volume stays down.

Any help will be appreciated. I have spent almost 10 days to find out the proper way to duck the music (keep it playing in background with lover volume) while TTS is playing and then at the end of the TTS re-level the volume of music.

Answer (score 0):

```
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setDelegate: self];
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback
               withOptions:AVAudioSessionCategoryOptionDuckOthers error:nil];
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setActive:YES error:nil];
```

Try this code to duck audio while playing TTS.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but that problem is solved or not I don't know as that project is been put on hold and I am not currently have access to that project code.